# A shell script to validate a column

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I have this script that is going to read in csv files that will be in directory. However I want the script to validate an entire coulmn of the .csv file before it moves to the second column i.e

```
Name, City
Joe, Orlando
Sam, Copper Town
Mike, Atlanta
```

So it has to check the coulmn NAMES first before it moveds on to check City? How would i make changes to the following script to cater to this?

```
       # Read all files.  no file have spaces in their names
  for file in /source/*.csv ; do
         # init two variables before processing a new file
  FILESTATUS=GOOD
  FIRSTROW=true
       # process file 1 line a time, splitting the line by the 
       # Internal Field Sep ,
  cat "${file}" | while IFS=, read field1 field2; do
       # Skip first line, the header row
  if [ "${FIRSTROW}" = "true" ]; then
     FIRSTROW=FALSE
        # skip processing of this line, continue with next record
     continue;
  fi

        #different validations
  if [[ "${field1}" = somestringprefix*  ]]; then
     ${FILESTATUS}=BAD
     # Stop inner loop
     break
  fi
  somecheckonField2
  done
    if [ ${FILESTATUS} = "GOOD" ] ; then
      mv ${file} /source/good
    else
      mv ${file} /source/bad
    fi
 done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `awk` in the inner loop:

```
if awk -F, '$1 !~/^prefix1/ || $2 !~ /^prefix2/ {exit(1)}' "$file" ; then
    mv "$file" good
else
    mv "$file" bad
fi
```

`^prefix1` and `^prefix2` are meant to be regex patterns.

Comment: Thanks but above script, does it iterate vertical check every field in a column rather than go horizontal which is the traditional apprach

Comment: It validates line by line. But if a line isn't valid, it stops further processing on that file and returns `1`